# How to force a where clause on a collection in laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a table that I am running a search on.  Foo.  I want to check if the search term is like a bunch of different fields in the table.  But I want the results to be forced to be "active".

I am using Laravel 5.0

```
    $foos = DB::table('foo')
        ->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
        ->orWhere('description', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
        ->orWhere('address_city', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
        ->orWhere('short_description', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
        ->orWhere('interview', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
        ->get();

    $foos = $foos->where('active', true)->get();
```

Comment: putting `->where('active', true)` before your first `where` doesn't work?

Comment: that was it. thanks

Comment: Seems weird to me that you'd want a `where` clause on the returned `Collection` instead of just adding another `where` clause to the DB query.

Comment: I am sorry I was wrong, that comment is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collection has a `where` method similar to query builder.

```
$activeFoos = $foos->where('active', true);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-where

Edit :
I understand what you need from the comments now. Try the code below, and also note that i changed your original $query to $find. So keep that in mind.

```
$foos = DB::table('foo')
    ->where('active', true)
    ->where(function ($query) use ($find) {
        $query->where('name', 'LIKE', "%{$find}%")
            ->orWhere('description', 'LIKE', "%{$find}%")
            ->orWhere('address_city', 'LIKE', "%{$find}%")
            ->orWhere('short_description', 'LIKE', "%{$find}%")
            ->orWhere('interview', 'LIKE', "%{$find}%");
    })
    ->get();
```

Comment: If you look that is what I am trying, it returns an error

Comment: can u see that i've removed the `->get()` ?

Comment: I am using laravel 5.0

Comment: Laravel 5.0 supports where and whereLoose on collections.
https://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html#method_where

Comment: That worked. thanks.  This is exactly what I was trying to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

Is the value of `active` actually true or just truthy (such as an integer of 1)?

For loose comparisons then you'll need to use `whereLoose('active', true)`, otherwise Laravel's method where() on Collections will perform strict type comparisons.

Like Sandeesh said, you'll need to remove the get() since get() is a query builder method, Collections where() methods return a new collection not a builder instance.

Comment: The value is actually an int: 1. However, if I pass the where to the main query with whereActive(1) it still gets some whereActive = 0.